# How to get Jetty thread dump?

Tags: jetty

I have a **Ubuntu Server 10.10 64-bit** running a web application on **Jetty 6.1.24-6** on **Sun's JVM**, both installed from standard Ubuntu repositories.

I'm trying to track down a problem with this server (100% cpu after some time, it might be related to a known bug on NIO's Selector, although it looks like changing the connector to old io SocketConnector didn't solve the problem!), and need to take a thread dump.

Unfortunately I'm unable to get the thread dump. I've tried to send a **SIGQUIT** to the process, and tried to attach **JStack** to it, but neither approach works.

I see no output at all from SIGQUIT (in any of the log files generated by Jetty), and JStack, even when run as root (or jetty) and with "-F", says that it has been attached to the process, but then blocks and produces no more output!

How can I obtain the thread dump?

Comment: See my question here, I have taken some Thread dumps that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404844/jetty-service-thread-crashes-and-uses-100-cpu

Answer (score 6):

You have to do this as the same user as the jetty process is running under. On Ubuntu this user is normally called jetty.

So try

```
sudo -u jetty jstack <pid>
```

this will send a thread dump to stdout (your shell).

You can also

```
sudo -u jetty kill -QUIT <pid>
```

which will send the thread dump to jetty's stdout (normally `/var/log/jetty/out.log`)

To get the pids use the `jps` command or `ps ax|grep java`

Comment: ```ps ax | grep java``` usually outputs several processes, which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

did you try VisualVM (/usr/lib/java-6-sun/bin/jvisualvm) with remote connection ? It can capture a thread dump

Comment: I don't know why, but it does not work. I've added some -D parameters to the JVM, the port 1099 is open at the server. I add a connection on VisualVM, it says "connecting..." but never go further. More strange is that the connection is indeed established, as shown by a 'netstat' both on the client (my machine) and on the server!

Comment: how did you establish the connection ? via JMX or a jstatd daemon ?

Comment: 1099 seems to be a port of a rmi registry... what url did you configure in your JMX connection ?

Comment: With visualvm it only asks for a host and port. I'm not sure if 1099 is the correct port. Look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755819/cpu-and-profiling-not-supported-for-remote-jvisualvm-session