# What is this port (JVM / Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, port

When I do a `netstat -tpnl | grep java` :

```
> tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                   
> LISTEN      1307/java tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*
> LISTEN      1307/java tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*
> LISTEN      1307/java tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*
> LISTEN      1307/java tcp6       0      0 :::33445                :::*
> LISTEN      1307/java tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*
> LISTEN      1307/java
```

a ps -eaf | grep java give this :

```
tomcat    1307     1  7 08:39 ?        00:01:24 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-instances/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms512m -Xmx4096m -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms512m -Xmx4096m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCCause -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/opt/tomcat/logs/gc.log.201710310839 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20 -XX:GCLogFileSize=200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/tomcat/logs/HeadDump_20171031083922.hdump -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-engine/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/tomcat-engine/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/tomcat-engine/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-instances/ -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-engine -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/tomcat-instances/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Here the port i know :

- Port 1099 : RMI
- Port 9999 : JMX
- Port 8009 : AJP
- Port 8005 : Shutdown
- Port 8080 : Tomcat

But what do the port 33445 ????

Thanks a lot,

Comment: not programming related, thus a bad fit for stackoverflow. But have you searched the internet for "port 33445"? Brings up quite some results for me. Most likely it's one of the applications that you've deployed.

Comment: I don't think so, because the port is a "random port" so search on Google won't help (already try).

Comment: You give no indication that it's random (unless you mean random as in https://xkcd.com/221/). 33445 gives google results for me. However, as your question is not programming related, it's still not a good fit for stackoverflow. If it was programming-related, you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry... not read the MCVE :/

Answer (score 1):

If that port definitely hasn't been opened by your application, then it could be the diagnostic attach port, used by JConsole, etc.

Try adding

```
-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism
```

to your JVM command line, and see if the port disappears.

Comment: Thank you Kevin   With JConsole, i am not able to connect the port 33445 (the port is "random" ; when I restart Tomcat, i have an other port). With your DisableAttachMechanism, the "random" port always present.

Comment: In my webapps directory, i drop all applications ! After restarting Tomcat, the "random port' is always present... :/

Comment: I'm sorry -- if this isn't the diagnostic attach port, I don't know what it is :/

Comment: Found (in part) : it is port use for JMX ! I fixed 2 ports (JMX and RMI) but there is  a third port...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884353/why-java-opens-3-ports-when-jmx-is-configured